How to make 3x3 images with single caption under each row with citation in LATEX?
I have nine different images that I want to show as 3x3 in latex.

I want to use the entire full page of the paper, which I can achieve via the figure* option.
I want a single caption for each set of 3 images on each row like (a), (b) & (c), which, with much difficulty, I was able to achieve with the caption* option.
Now, the problem is during the citation of images. I cannot cite 1a, 1b, or 1c.
I have attached a picture showing the output format required. The images are marked from 1 to 9.
Can anybody help me with it?
Thank you.


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Note that subcaption provides two references for each subfigure caption, accessable as \ref and \subref, which have different formats.


I am unable to [cross-reference], say, 1a, 1b, or 1c.

Don't use \caption*{}. Instead, do use \caption{}. That way, you can create cross-references with the help of the LaTeX \label-\ref mechanism.

\documentclass[twocolumn,demo]{article} % or some other suitable document class
% Be sure to remove the 'demo' option in your real document.

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} % optional

\begin{document}

The images in figure \ref{fig:9g-b} demonstrate \dots

The images in \cref{fig:9g-b,fig:9g-c} demonstrate \dots

\begin{figure*}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.3\textwidth} % set default width

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics{fig1}\hfill
\includegraphics{fig2}\hfill
\includegraphics{fig3}
\caption{} \label{fig:9g-a}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics{fig4}\hfill
\includegraphics{fig5}\hfill
\includegraphics{fig6}
\caption{} \label{fig:9g-b}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics{fig7}\hfill
\includegraphics{fig8}\hfill
\includegraphics{fig9}
\caption{} \label{fig:9g-c}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A figure with 9 graphs} \label{fig:9g}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}


You are correct, but if I don't use caption* then the captions below each row of images is shown with double brackets like ((a)) , ((b)) & ((c)). So how to get rid of these double brackets?

@RON -- Did you actually compile my example code? It produces (a), (b), and (c), not ((a)) , ((b)), and ((c)). If you're getting something other than (a), (b), and (c) in your document, it must be because you're overriding some of the default settings of the caption and/or subcaption packages. Sadly -- but probably also unsurprisingly -- my mind-reading and other psychic abilities are utterly worthless. Thus, unless you provide some much-needed additional information about your document setup, I can't provide any further help.

You don't want to use \caption*.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

% local command to ease input
\newcommand{\pseudocaption}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\begin{subfigure}{1cm}\caption{#1}\end{subfigure}}%
}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l c c c @{}}
& S1 & S2 & S3 \\[2ex]
G1
& \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
& \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
& \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
\\
& \pseudocaption{\label{first}} \\[2ex]
G15
& \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
& \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
& \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
\\
& \pseudocaption{\label{second}} \\[2ex]
G29
& \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
& \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
& \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image}
\\
& \pseudocaption{\label{third}}
\end{tabular}

\caption{The caption for the whole thing\label{full}}

\end{figure}

We refer to figure~\ref{full} and to subfigures
\ref{first},~\ref{second} and~\ref{third}.

\end{document}


